# Bit Syntax and Binary Representation in Erlang

Tags: erlang, byte, bit, bit-shift

I'm trying to get my head around the Bit Syntax in Erlang and I'm having some trouble understand how this works:

```
Red = 10.
Green = 61.
Blue = 20.
Color = << Red:5, Green:6, Blue:5 >> .
```

I've seen this example in the Software for a concurrent world by Joe Armstrong second edition and this code will

> create a 16 bit memory area containing a single RGB triplet.

My question is how can 3 bytes be packed in a 16-bit memory area?. I'm not familiar whatsoever with bit shifting and I wasn't able to find anything relevant to this subject referring to erlang as well. My understand so far is that the segment is made up of 16 parts and that Red occupies 5, green 6 and blue 5 however I'm note sure how this is even possible.

Given that

```
61 = 0011011000110001
```

which alone is 16 bits how is this packaging possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, 61 is only equal to `00110110 00110001` if you store it as two ASCII digits.  When written in binary, 61 is `111101`.

Note that the binary representation requires six binary digits, or six "bits" for short.  That's what we're taking advantage of in this line:

```
Color = << Red:5, Green:6, Blue:5 >> .
```

We're using 5 bits for the red value, 6 bits for the green value, and 5 bits for the blue value, for a total of 16 bits.  This works since the red value and the blue value are both less than 32 (since 31 is the largest number that can be represented with 5 bits), and the green value is less than 64 (since 63 is the largest number that can be represented with 6 bits).

The complete value is `01010 111101 10100` (three segments for red, green and blue), or if we split it into two bytes, `01010111 10110100`.